# What is the coat of arms on these textiles?

Tags: heraldry

What is the coat of arm in the given images of mainly scarfs?

It says "Made in Germany" on the tag and gives as the [Woolmark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woolmark) number "23019966".

[image]

[image]

Other instances of using this company logo as coat-of-arms are

[image] [image] [image]

Comment: Why do you think it's German? Also, please edit your answer to say where you have looked already (to avoid others duplicating your research).  Thank you.

Comment: In English heraldic blason it would be described as "Gules (red), on a bend (diagonal band) sable (black) between two quatrefiols or (goldor yellow) 5 (somethings?) argent (silver or white)".   There seem to be two lion supporters and a crown on top.  I don't know if the thing beneath the shield and hte lions is supposed to be a "compartment" or a scroll for a motto.  I don't know whether this is an inaccurate version of a real coat of arms or a more or less semi heraldic fake coat of arms.

Comment: I suspect it is a fake. I tried a Google Lens search with a re-drawn coat, made from the elements @MAGolding described (cinquefoil argent for the objects in the band, left off the compartment), and nothing came up.

Comment: I hope this shows the grafic I used: https://lens.google.com/search?p=AU55jv37M1QvRdPyAMadrvXICXsYQIFf1s16y9eO5yI5-3_B3mFGUjVew_7L1WiZ-dooIXnXqYoz9urWjMSGSnYO8ovxi6ZO3zDs19_p4WrkWEc3nVeoy7tfJeUKDQ-8lgMSJYobBPD8BAdn1H8UsoelSGvsTR9NszmyFUaMCnenkHLbv_Fu49BblHU03FnE_mXV2iC11lmU3MJj629Haf4jz0XYTrx3h2mNdveoLjngCQKmeBOU-5kS&ep=gisbubb&hl=de#lns=W251bGwsbnVsbCxudWxsLG51bGwsbnVsbCxudWxsLG51bGwsIkVrY0tKR1F3WW1ZNFl6YzBMV0l3WVRBdE5HUXpNaTFpWmpZeExXTTRPVFUxT1RJNU5Ea3lPQklmWXpselpYQjNRa1IwZDBWbU5FaEZlRmhpTFdJNVpVSk1hMHRXWkZGQ1p3PT0iXQ==

Comment: FWIW, clothing article names for some weird reason are highly localized in English. Here in the US I believe we'd call the article of clothing pictured a "scarf". A "muffler" is a part of a car's exhaust system. I'm guessing its the word for "scarf" in the dialect of English you have learned?

Comment: @ccprog Not sure whether it might help (with reverse drawing this logo/CoA, but a different pic like this: https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/yp8AAOSwcaVjCIy6/s-l1600.jpg or https://www.dba.dk/halstoerklaede-garant-nyt/id-1089236597/ https://shafa.ua/women/aksessuary/sharfy-i-platki/30186184-shotlandskiy-sharf-kletka-chistaya-sherst-germaniya (The item number seems to lead somehwere? Is this a 'generic logo' to random woolmark-paid membership? Someone (perhaps in Germany right now) might walk up to a textile salesforce guy and just ask what's the brand/company for/behind this? Doubtful of origin?)

Comment: @MAGolding I wish a written-out description of the visuals were standard for picture ID Qs. If only such descriptions could somehow wind up in the body of the question text?

Comment: it's a clothes label. It's almost certainly made up :)

Comment: @T.E.D. - _Muffler_ is a rather outdated British term for a thick scarf; I know it mainly from books.